I can no longer deactivate venv
Terminal
After activating venv, I deleted the venv directory without deactivating it from the VSCode GUI, thinking "I don't need this virtual environment after all. After doing so, I could no longer exit the virtual environment using the deactivate command.
Is there any way to resolve this?
Try deactivate
Activate another venv and deactivate
ctrl + c

Please post text here as text, no need for a screenshot for two lines of terminal output.

Deleting the virtual environment directory: it deletes the script that the deactivate command relies on.
Restart your terminal: This will clear the current shell session and remove any environment variables associated with the deleted virtual environment.
I hope this helps.

Thank you. Restarting the terminal solved the problem.
